# Issue scraping website with reactive blocks

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract the business name/address information from a website listing clinic locations. The locations that are displayed depend upon the search parameters in the Google Maps widget. My goal is to collect information about all of them in the US, so I zoomed out and tried the following in both Map & List View:

List View:

```
fyz <- read_html("https://www.fyzical.com/Locations')
> loc_text <- fyz %>%
+   html_nodes("div.psl-text-content") %>%
+   html_text()
> loc_text
character(0)
```

And then in Map View:

```
> loc <- fyz %>%
+   html_nodes("script") %>%
+   .[str_detect(., "maps\\.google")] %>%
+   str_extract_all("\".*maps\\.google.*\"")
Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
> loc
list()
```

Both came up empty. Using SelectorGadget to paste in the XPath produced the same results. I'm relatively new to this, so any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to zoom, interactively, you'll probably need to use RSelenium.  Here's how I did it.  First, use this to navigate to the website.  You should see the address bar with slated alternating light and dark red stripes in it.

```
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- rsDriver(browser='firefox', phantomver=NULL)
brow <- remDr[["client"]]
brow$open()
brow$navigate("https://www.fyzical.com/Locations")
```

Go to the browser that has the fyzical website loaded:

[image]

Then, input a zip code and zoom the map out to where you want it.  Following that, do this:

```
library(rvest)
h <- read_html(brow$getPageSource()[[1]])
addresses <- h %>% html_elements(css=".psl-text-address") %>% html_text()
head(addresses)
# [1] "6415 Kenai Spur Hwy, Kenai, AK, 99611"       "650 N Shoreline Dr, Wasilla, AK, 99654"     
# [3] "832 Princeton Ave SW, Birmingham, AL, 35211" "602 Corley Avenue, Boaz, AL, 35957"         
# [5] "1218 13th Avenue SE, Decatur, AL, 35601"     "101 Hwy 80 West, Demopolis, AL, 36732"
```

You'll see that the address list should have 445 entries. I've printed the first six here.