# web scraping Javascript heavy site using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to webscrape the full list of projects and associated details from this site (the Project List is on the right hand side):

```
https://www.forest-trends.org/project-list/
```

I cannot seem to identify the correct css elements to get at the project and associated details. I wondered if this was something to do with JavaScript within the html?

When I try the following:

```
library(rvest)
link <- "https://www.forest-trends.org/project-list"
urlData <- link %>% read_html %>% html_nodes(".project-tile")
```

I would expect to get a list of projects. Instead I get:

```
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

How to return the full list of projects and associated details?

Comment: @Nad Pat's comment about the API is likely the best route.  If you wanted to scrape the page, you might need RSelenium instead. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70836215/issue-scraping-website-with-reactive-blocks/70837625#70837625) is an answer to a similar question that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There an `API` which you can use,

```
library(jsonlite)
df = fromJSON('https://www.forest-trends.org/wp-content/themes/foresttrends/map_tools/project_fetch.php?ids=')
head(df$markers)
           lat          lng                       type
1 -11.78449871 -70.73347813 Forest and land-use carbon
2    17.067346    94.459977 Forest and land-use carbon
3     3.054216   -72.333984 Forest and land-use carbon
4     20.98685    -89.03344 Forest and land-use carbon
5    -0.886093      30.5798 Forest and land-use carbon
6    -1.809978    31.131299 Forest and land-use carbon
                                                                                                                  title               location pid  size
1                                                                                           Reforestadores REDD Project    Madre de Dios, Peru   1 85000
2 Reforestation and Restoration of degraded mangrove lands, sustainable livelihood and community development in Myanmar                Myanmar   2  2575
3                                                                              San Nicolas Carbon Sequestration Project San Nicholas, Colombia   3  7300
4                                                                                             Amigos de Calakmul Mexico     Selva Maya, Mexico   4 56700
5                                                                          Uganda Nile Basin Reforestation Project No 4                 Uganda   5   347
6                                                                                                    Emiti Nibwo Bulora    Nyaishozi, Tanzania   6   130
```

Comment: Good spot! That's certainly an easy solution.