# Using RSelenium to webscrape multiple item locations on a map

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to webscrape a map inorder to download all locations within a Street Lighting layer. I use `RSelenium` to get the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

# Open a browser
rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
# Navigate to site
remDr$navigate("https://gis2.westberks.gov.uk/webapps/OnlineMap/")
```

At this point, via the browser, I switch on the Street Lighting layer (under Highways) and then select a single Street Light on the map. If I then run:

```
h <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]) %>% html_nodes(".attrTable") %>% html_table()
```

I get the data for that single Street Light. However, I want to get the data for *all* street lighting displayed on the map. I don't know how to do this. Is it possible to programmatically select all lights on the map before running `remDr$getPageSource()` ?

I've looked at this post, but doesn't quite solve the problem:
[Issue scraping website with reactive blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70836215/issue-scraping-website-with-reactive-blocks/70837625#70837625)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It displays layer as single image and you can't get positions.
It would need some `Computer Vision` to detect circles on image.

When you click map then it sends coordinates to server
and it send back `JSON data` which it displays as popup window.

It sends something like this (with some values `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax`)

https://gis2.westberks.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/maps/Wbc_Highways/MapServer/11/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A442520.89976831735%2C%22ymin%22%3A178788.66371417744%2C%22xmax%22%3A443314.65135582053%2C%22ymax%22%3A179582.41530168062%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A27700%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A27700%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=27700&outFields=OBJECTID%2CItem_Type%2CItem_Identity_Code%2CLocation_Description%2CAssigned_Street%2CLocality%2CTown%2CType%2CBracket_Type%2CLantern_Type%2CLamp_Type%2CBallast_Type%2CControl_Type%2CSign_Lantern_Type%2CSign_Bracket_Type%2CSign_Post_Type%2CBollard_Base_Type%2CBollard_Shell_Type%2CColumn_Manufacturer%2CMaterial_Type%2CLamp_Wattage%2CLantern_Manufacturer%2CNumber_of_Lamps%2CSwitching_Regime_Code%2CSwitching_Regime%2CLamp_Type2%2CEasting%2CNorthing&outSR=27700

(you can click link to see JSON data)

Maybe if you use it with `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` for bigger area then you get all values.

---

**EDIT:**

I don't have experience in `R` but I can show example in `Python`.

It doesn't need Selenium (in `Python` and in `R`).

```py
import requests

# full url with parameters
#url = 'https://gis2.westberks.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/maps/Wbc_Highways/MapServer/11/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A442520.89976831735%2C%22ymin%22%3A178788.66371417744%2C%22xmax%22%3A443314.65135582053%2C%22ymax%22%3A179582.41530168062%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A27700%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A27700%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=27700&outFields=OBJECTID%2CItem_Type%2CItem_Identity_Code%2CLocation_Description%2CAssigned_Street%2CLocality%2CTown%2CType%2CBracket_Type%2CLantern_Type%2CLamp_Type%2CBallast_Type%2CControl_Type%2CSign_Lantern_Type%2CSign_Bracket_Type%2CSign_Post_Type%2CBollard_Base_Type%2CBollard_Shell_Type%2CColumn_Manufacturer%2CMaterial_Type%2CLamp_Wattage%2CLantern_Manufacturer%2CNumber_of_Lamps%2CSwitching_Regime_Code%2CSwitching_Regime%2CLamp_Type2%2CEasting%2CNorthing&outSR=27700'

# only parameters
params = {
    'f': ['json'],
    'geometry': [
         '{"xmin":442520.89976831735,"ymin":178788.66371417744,"xmax":443314.65135582053,"ymax":179582.41530168062,"spatialReference":{"wkid":27700,"latestWkid":27700}}'
    ],
    'geometryType': ['esriGeometryEnvelope'],
    'inSR': ['27700'],
    'outFields': ['OBJECTID,Item_Type,Item_Identity_Code,Location_Description,Assigned_Street,Locality,Town,Type,Bracket_Type,Lantern_Type,Lamp_Type,Ballast_Type,Control_Type,Sign_Lantern_Type,Sign_Bracket_Type,Sign_Post_Type,Bollard_Base_Type,Bollard_Shell_Type,Column_Manufacturer,Material_Type,Lamp_Wattage,Lantern_Manufacturer,Number_of_Lamps,Switching_Regime_Code,Switching_Regime,Lamp_Type2,Easting,Northing'],
    'outSR': ['27700'],
    'returnGeometry': ['true'],
    'spatialRel': ['esriSpatialRelIntersects']
}

# url without parameters
url = 'https://gis2.westberks.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/maps/Wbc_Highways/MapServer/11/query'

response = requests.get(url, params=params)
#print(response.url)
#print(response.status_code)

data = response.json()

for item in data['features']:
    print('Locality:', item['attributes']['Locality'].strip())
    print('Town    :', item['attributes']['Town'].strip())
    print('Street  :', item['attributes']['Assigned_Street'].strip())
    print('Geometry:', item['geometry'])
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
Locality: BRIGHTWALTON
Town    : NEWBURY
Street  : SAXONS ACRE
Geometry: {'x': 442763, 'y': 179193}
---
Locality: BRIGHTWALTON
Town    : NEWBURY
Street  : ASH CLOSE
Geometry: {'x': 442782, 'y': 179248}
---
Locality: BRIGHTWALTON
Town    : NEWBURY
Street  : SAXONS ACRE
Geometry: {'x': 442770, 'y': 179214}
---
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version in `R`

```r
> install.packages("jsonlite")

> library(jsonlite)

> URL = 'https://gis2.westberks.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/maps/Wbc_Highways/MapServer/11/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A442520.89976831735%2C%22ymin%22%3A178788.66371417744%2C%22xmax%22%3A443314.65135582053%2C%22ymax%22%3A179582.41530168062%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A27700%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A27700%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=27700&outFields=OBJECTID%2CItem_Type%2CItem_Identity_Code%2CLocation_Description%2CAssigned_Street%2CLocality%2CTown%2CType%2CBracket_Type%2CLantern_Type%2CLamp_Type%2CBallast_Type%2CControl_Type%2CSign_Lantern_Type%2CSign_Bracket_Type%2CSign_Post_Type%2CBollard_Base_Type%2CBollard_Shell_Type%2CColumn_Manufacturer%2CMaterial_Type%2CLamp_Wattage%2CLantern_Manufacturer%2CNumber_of_Lamps%2CSwitching_Regime_Code%2CSwitching_Regime%2CLamp_Type2%2CEasting%2CNorthing&outSR=27700'

> data <- fromJSON(URL)

> library(magrittr)  # to use `%>%
> data <- URL %>% fromJSON

> data$features$attributes$Locality

[1] "BRIGHTWALTON                                                                                        "
[2] "BRIGHTWALTON                                                                                        "
[3] "BRIGHTWALTON                                                                                        "

> data$features$attributes$Town

[1] "NEWBURY                                                                                             "
[2] "NEWBURY                                                                                             "
[3] "NEWBURY                                                                                             "

> data$features$attributes$Assigned_Street

[1] "SAXONS ACRE                                                                                         "
[2] "ASH CLOSE                                                                                           "
[3] "SAXONS ACRE                                                                                         "

> data$features$geometry

       x      y
1 442763 179193
2 442782 179248
3 442770 179214

> library(stringr)

> data$features$attributes$Locality %>% str_trim

[1] "BRIGHTWALTON" "BRIGHTWALTON" "BRIGHTWALTON"
```

---

**EDIT:**

Something similar to `Python` version

```
> library(magrittr)  # to use `%>%
> library(httr)
> library(jsonlite)

> URL = 'https://gis2.westberks.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/maps/Wbc_Highways/MapServer/11/query'

> query = list(
    f = list('json'),
    geometry = list(
         '{"xmin":442520.89976831735,"ymin":178788.66371417744,"xmax":443314.65135582053,"ymax":179582.41530168062,"spatialReference":{"wkid":27700,"latestWkid":27700}}'
    ),
    geometryType = list('esriGeometryEnvelope'),
    inSR = list('27700'),
    outFields = list('OBJECTID,Item_Type,Item_Identity_Code,Location_Description,Assigned_Street,Locality,Town,Type,Bracket_Type,Lantern_Type,Lamp_Type,Ballast_Type,Control_Type,Sign_Lantern_Type,Sign_Bracket_Type,Sign_Post_Type,Bollard_Base_Type,Bollard_Shell_Type,Column_Manufacturer,Material_Type,Lamp_Wattage,Lantern_Manufacturer,Number_of_Lamps,Switching_Regime_Code,Switching_Regime,Lamp_Type2,Easting,Northing'),
    outSR = list('27700'),
    returnGeometry = list('true'),
    spatialRel = list('esriSpatialRelIntersects')
  )

> response <- GET(URL, query=query)
> data <- response %>% content %>% fromJSON

> data <- GET(URL, query=query) %>% content %>% fromJSON

> items <- data$features
```

Comment: In R, we can use `jsonlite::fromJSON()` to read JSON data

Comment: @NadPat I try to build example in `R` using `jsonlite` and `httr` but something goes wrong. If you have experience in `R` then you could get link from my answer and create new answer with example in `R`

Comment: it I hope it will not block access when you use it too many times :)

Comment: How did you create the JSON query? I cannot find it in the page HTML

Comment: you may not find it in HTML because it can be in some JavaScript code or it is generated in code. I used `DevTool` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab: `Network`) to see all requests send from browser to server - and I get this URL from `DevTool`. In Python I used some function to convert string with URL to dictionary `params` - so later I could simply replace `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax`, but I don't have experience to do the same in `R` - so I keep it as string. You will have to replace values directly in string, or maybe create something similar to `params` and maybe it could work with `httr::GET`

Comment: I created something similar to Python version - all params as list - see answer.